# Should Windows services be built as Windows Application or Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, console-application

This question ISN'T about whether to use a service versus a non-service (there are several SO questions that cover this already).

Given that I've decided to go with a service, should it be built as Windows Application or Console Application?

I ask because I used the Visual Studio 2015 service project template (Visual C#/Windows/Classic Desktop/Windows Service) to create a practice project, and it defaulted to Windows Application. Had I tried to predict beforehand what it would have chosen, I would have incorrectly predicted Console Application.

I suspect either would actually work in the end, but to satisfy my coder OCD, is there a sound technical rationale for one or the other (such as avoiding spinning up a needless conhost.exe process or something)?

FWIW, I'm using C#/.NET 4.0.

Comment: You can use Windows Service template in Add New Project window.

Comment: What do you mean "Windows Application"? A WinForms project? Any project that runs on Windows is a "Windows Application", including a "Console Application".

Comment: @gunr2171 there's a flag in the PE header which tells if an executable image is a GUI app or a console app (look in `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.Subsystem`)

Comment: "Windows Application" is Visual Studio's own description, as seen on the Application tab of the project properties, on the right-hand side under "Output type:". Most people just say "winforms" as shorthand for this.

Comment: @amonroejj, ah ok. I thought you were talking about a project type "Windows Application".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Windows Service template in Add New Project window.

If for any reason (like using Express edition of Visual Studio) you want to create it using a different template, you can use Windows Forms Application template.

If you take a look at properties of a Windows Service project you will see:

[image]

To do so, you can create project using Windows Forms Application template.
Then add a reference to `System.ServiceProcess` assembly. Also you don't need Assemblies like `System.Windows.Forms` or `System.Drawing` in references. Then using Add New Item window, add a new Windows Service and change the `Program.cs` to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
namespace WindowsService1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information take a look at [How to: Create Windows Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I don't think we're on the same wavelength here. My question is not a "how to do this" question. It's a "which of two options, and more importantly, why" question.

Comment: At least since the output type of Windows Service Template is Windows Application,  using Windows Application as start point is acceptable. I didn't say don't use Console Application template, but seeing that Output Type is enough reason for me to use Windows Application.

Comment: For example if you start it by creating a Console Application, you will see a Console window at execution.